# highCharts:when color of data set undefiend,slice is white in piechart

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I wanna to set the color for each data in `Piechart`, and in some slices I wanna show the default color. I read in the Highcharts API that it must be set to `undefined`, but it does not work for me.

```
 $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'pie'
    },
    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, {
            y: 216.4,
            color: undefined
        }, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cupom1nv/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Samira jan, `color: undefined` makes ONE slice color default! This is not the example for you. Go to this link:

http://jsfiddle.net/8QufV/

Comment: I wanna mark the highest point with the color, but I create Json Object on server side, and "color" property in my object is created.

Comment: and all of my data has the color property. for example,I wanna mark the highest point with red color and other points use defualt color. It works for me in column type [link]http://jsfiddle.net/cupom1nv/2/      but it does`n work for pie chart:  [link]http://jsfiddle.net/cupom1nv/3/

Comment: tank Raeen,  I think that it is a bug in highchart!!  I know that i can remove this property, but this property  is exist in my json object.I must ignore color property when it is null. I`m using asp.net. I do not success yet.

Comment: Then why just don't you use null instead? See: http://jsfiddle.net/cupom1nv/5/ Anyway, what do you mean default color for a pie? Each slice has own color anyway..

Comment: Just checked our bug tracker and found [this](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1288) - feel free to add your comment there.